# PIL remove colour mixing between colour regions

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have images with very few colours in them. (5 different colours max, and all are quite distinct.)

At the boundaries of the regions between colours, there is a (usually single pixel wide) line of a mix between these colours. How can I remove this?

I do manipulation with them as a numpy array afterwards anyways, so if this can be achieved with a numpy array, that works too.

For example, this image:

[image: 10*10 white, 1*10 (.25, .25, .25) and 10*10 black]

Which is made from this array:

```
image = np.append(
    np.append(np.ones((10, 10, 3)), np.ones((1, 10, 3)) / 5., axis=0),
    np.zeros((10, 10, 3)), axis=0
)

# Or a 10 * 10 white (0, 0, 0) region with a 1 * 10 line of (0.2, 0.2, 0.2) pixels
# underneath and a 10 * 10 black (1, 1, 1) region underneath that.

# Expected result:
expected = np.append(np.ones((10, 10, 3)), np.zeros((11, 10, 3)), axis=0)
```

I would like a function that converts that 1 * 10 line of grey pixels into black, as it is closer to black.

Comment: How would you define the boundaries there? As in how do you locate those?

Comment: @Divakar Little thin areas that are not a major colour but appear near a major colour in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Image.quantize`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.quantize) to force all colors to match your palette. This changes the mode of your image to `P`, convert it back to `RGB` when you're done.

Comment: Using this along with [`Image.getcolors`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors) to count the "major" colours works perfect. Thanks!